# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension chrome : that gives a pop-up and does an automatic click on my cart where the id is set by Me from inspect element.

Although i was not able to write a code where i can set id to specific class elements on a website (any website with help of Chrome extension)

What happens when i run this code after setting the id of that element manually by inspect element:

I have tried various method like document.getElementByid().click();

and with variable method also but none of them worked

```
   jQuery.noConflict();
    {
        var my_text=prompt('Enter Your Tickets ');
        addclick(my_text);

    }

    function addclick(v){
        var button;
        for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
            //document.getElementById('clicker').click();
            button = document.getElementById('clicker')
                button.click();
                alert(i);


        }
    }
```

These script runs perfectly if you try to run it from console but doesn't from Chrome extension even after all permission are set

Error I received :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: Are you referring to an element's `id` or `class`? You use both in your question. And `Cannot read property 'click' of null` means that `document.getElementById('clicker')` returned nothing - are you sure there's an element on the page with the `id` of `clicker`?

Comment: Also, what are you expecting your `for` loop to do? `i = 1; i <= v; i++` is cycling between 1 and `v`, where in your case `v` is the result of whatever `prompt('Enter Your Tickets ')` returns (which might not be a number)

Comment: I am referring to document.getElementById('clicker') , and yes there is an element on the page I have added it manually  but i also have a script to add on the page automatically by using the class 

code for adding id to class 

jQuery('.btn-pls').attr('id', 'clicker');

Comment: I am expecting the loop to get my number and click for me on the '+' button in the cart for v number of times

Comment: Well like I said, that error happens when `document.getElementById('clicker')` returns nothing. So chances are, nothing with that id is on the page or something janky is going on. Either way, can you please make a [mcve] that demonstrates the error you're getting and add it to your question (in a runnable code block)?

Comment: jQuery('.btn-pls').attr('id', 'clicker');
 {
        var my_text=prompt('Enter Your Tickets ');
        addclick(my_text);

    }

    function addclick(v){
        for(i=1; i<=v; i++)
            {
                //document.getElementById('clicker').click();
    var button = document.getElementById('clicker');
             button.click();
    alert(i);
  }
    }

Comment: Please follow this link for code of example https://tech.io/snippet/8F8PDq6

Answer (score 3):

Your code runs before the `#clicker` element loaded (since it's above it); therefore, that element **does not exist** at that moment, `document.getElementById` returns `null` and hence the error.

To solve it, wrap your code by a function, and call it via [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3) or the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(()=>{
    var my_text=prompt('Enter Your Tickets ');
    addclick(my_text);
})

function addclick(v){
    var button;
    for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
        //document.getElementById('clicker').click();
        button = document.getElementById('clicker')
        button.click();
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    var my_text=prompt('Enter Your Tickets ');
    addclick(my_text);
})

function addclick(v){
    var button;
    for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
        //document.getElementById('clicker').click();
        button = document.getElementById('clicker')
        button.click();
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Here are runnable snippets with your full code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(() => {
      jQuery('.btn-pls').attr('id', 'clicker'); {
        var my_text = prompt('Enter Your Tickets ');
        addclick(my_text);

      }
    })

    function addclick(v) {
      for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
        //document.getElementById('clicker').click();
        var button = document.getElementById('clicker');
        button.click();
        alert(i);
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .cart-item-btns .v-button {
      float: right;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 2px;
      min-width: 75px;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    .cart-item-main {
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .catalog-item.selected {
      background-color: #fecc00;
      cursor: default;
    }
    
    .catalog-item {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .catalog-item.selected {
      background-color: #fecc00;
      cursor: default;
    }
    
    .cart-item:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Chrome Extension By Love Chauhan</div><br/>
  <div class="cart-item-btns">
    <div class="v-button btn-qty hl-green"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-pls hl-green"><i class="fa fa-plus" id="clicker"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-min hl-green disabled"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-del hl-red"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-seat hl-green disabled v-hidden" title="limited capacity 40 new - VisitaSingoli
"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      jQuery('.btn-pls').attr('id', 'clicker'); {
        var my_text = prompt('Enter Your Tickets ');
        addclick(my_text);

      }
    })

    function addclick(v) {
      for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
        //document.getElementById('clicker').click();
        var button = document.getElementById('clicker');
        button.click();
        alert(i);
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .cart-item-btns .v-button {
      float: right;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 2px;
      min-width: 75px;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    .cart-item-main {
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .catalog-item.selected {
      background-color: #fecc00;
      cursor: default;
    }
    
    .catalog-item {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .catalog-item.selected {
      background-color: #fecc00;
      cursor: default;
    }
    
    .cart-item:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Chrome Extension By Love Chauhan</div><br/>
  <div class="cart-item-btns">
    <div class="v-button btn-qty hl-green"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-pls hl-green"><i class="fa fa-plus" id="clicker"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-min hl-green disabled"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-del hl-red"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div>
    <div class="v-button btn-seat hl-green disabled v-hidden" title="limited capacity 40 new - VisitaSingoli
"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Still getting this error

Comment: @LoveChauhan I've included two runnable snippets with your full code. **It does work.**

Comment: https://ibb.co/PtJMkF3
https://ibb.co/YdXn0cP

Check this image 
https://ibb.co/PtJMkF3
https://ibb.co/YdXn0cP

Code ;
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c_s_YxcHKukATTgY0bgpN-_uV8fsaX6s

Comment: Two more links to show the proof of code :-https://ibb.co/XWZ7jvp
https://ibb.co/S52rdqs

Answer (score 0):

Besides waiting for the DOM to load and to prevent unwanted errors try:

```
var button = document.getElementById('clicker')
if (button) {
    button.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, But I have used DOM elements to solve my issues.

Thanks once again.

Cheers !!!